# Widgets menu does not appear under "Appearance" in dashboard

Tags: themes, widgets

I am developing a WordPress theme, but am stuck on widgetizing my theme.

I have followed several tutorials but still cannot get it to work.
My widgets menu does not appear under *Appearance* in my dashboard.

This is my function file and sidebar.
From [*function.php*](http://pastebin.com/X679LmVM):

```
function custom_enqueue_scripts() {

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

        wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bin/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js', 'jquery', '1.10.1',TRUE);
        wp_register_script( 'fittext', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bin/js/jquery.fittext.js', 'jquery', '1.0',TRUE );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'fittext' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_scripts' );

if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {

        register_sidebar(array(
                'name' => 'Widgetized Area',
                'id'   => 'katuhu',
                'description'   => 'This is a widgetized area.',
                'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget'  => '</div>',
                'before_title'  => '<h4>',
                'after_title'   => '</h4>'
        ));

}
```

From [*sidebar.php*](http://pastebin.com/0TvAKBZy):

```
<div id="katuhu">

<?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Widgetized Area')) : else : ?>

<div class="pre-widget">
    <p><strong>Widgetized Area</strong></p>
    <p>This panel is active and ready for you to add some widgets via the WP Admin</p>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

The file name is [`functions.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File), not `function.php`. Note the "s". Otherwise, the code should work, and does work when I try it.